# Integral with only a list of values

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals

I am supposed to perform an integral of function $y(x)$ from say $x_1$ to $x_2$. 
Now the issue is I don't have an actual function $y(x)$, but I do have a list of values for $y$ and $x$.

In what way could I calculate the "integral"? It's okay if I have one value of the "integral" for each value of $x$ and $y$. 
So instead of ending up with a function as the result of my integral, I would end up with another list of values of the same length as the list of $x$ and $y$ values.

Comment: You can use quite a lot of different numerical methods to obtain the integral, but you cannot evaluate the error given by the method as you have a list of points. You can find more about this from google, search for "Numerical integration".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the trapezoid rule. You can find information on this here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule

The integral can be interpreted as the area "under" the curve. You can approximate this area using the trapezoid rule, which will give you a value.

Comment: What do you mean "The integral can be interpreted as the area "under" the curve"? The integral *defines* the area under the curve.

Comment: I was a bit vague about the meaning of "under" because: suppose $a<b<c<d$ and suppose $f(a<x\leq b),f(c\leq x<d)\geq 0$ and $f(b\leq x\leq c)<0$. Then the the integral on $[a,d]$ does not define the area "under" (i.e. between the function and the x-axis), since the contribution of the integral on $[b,c]$ will be negative. Area is by definition always positive, so we need to be careful. Also, consider $\int_0^1 x^{−1/2}$. We have $\lim_{x→0}x^{−1/2}=\infty$, but the area under the curve is perfectly finite.

Answer (score 1):

For sure, as pbs answered, adding the surface of the trapezoids is a way to go.

However, you can do slightly better if, by chance, you have an odd number of data points. The method consists in fitting three data points by a parabola and integrate the resulting equation.

Consider points $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$, $(x_3,y_3)$ and you want the area between $x_1$ and $x_3$. So, make $$y=a+b x+c x^2$$ and adjust the coefficients $a,b,c$ in order they be along the parabola. They are given by $$c=\frac{x_3 (y_2-y_1)+x_2 (y_1-y_3)+x_1 (y_3-y_2)}{(x_1-x_2) (x_1-x_3)
   (x_2-x_3)}$$ $$b=\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}-c(x_1+x_2)$$  $$a=y_1-bx_1-cx_1^2$$ Now $$\int_{x_1}^{x_3}y\, dx=a (x_3-x_1)+\frac b2 (x_3^2-x_1^2)+\frac c6 (x_3^3-x_1^3)$$ Just do it for all triplets $[x_1,x_2,x_3]$, $[x_3,x_4,x_5]$, $[x_5,x_6,x_7]$, $\cdots,$ $[x_{2n-1},x_{2n},x_{2n+1}]$.

If you have an even number of points, do the same up to only one pair of point remains and use the trapezoid rule for this last piece.

*All of the above was done assuming that the $x_i$'s are not equally spaced. If they were, there are very nice, simple and accurate methods to perform this integration. If you face such a case, post it and I shall put more in my answer.*